# Is there any way to open a URL within a Cordova app

Tags: cordova

Is there anyway to open a URL (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/) within a Cordova app without making use of the system browser?

Comment: you can put it in iframe which, it's work perfectly with me :)

Comment: @AnasOmar Sounds like a clever solution, can you post a demo of what you did?

Comment: Use inAppBrowser plugin with _blank param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am working with ionic so this what we do in our app

```
<ion-view view-title="your-title" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" scroll="false" class="no-header" fab-scroll-container>
     <iframe ng-src="the-website-link" class="my-iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>


</ion-content>
```

and this is the css

```
.takaful-iframe{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```